# geom_smooth does not seem to fit method="glm" with method.args correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, methods, glm

I am trying to fit a glm line with geom_smooth but the fitting does not seem correct. I get a very straight line. I would expect a slight curve to the line of fit, since I am using 'generalized linear model' and not linear.

Here is how my data structure looks like:

```
 $ treatment        : int  -20 -20 -40 -60 -60 -60 0 -100 -100 -40 ...
 $ response         : int  267 253 254 253 257 242 250 274 295 255 ...
 $ early_late       : Factor w/ 2 levels "early","late": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

And my code:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = data, mapping = aes(x= treatment, y= response, color=early_late, fill = early_late), shape = 21, size = 2.5, alpha = 0.15) + 
   scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(120,320, 40),  limits=c(120, 320)) + 
  labs(x= "treatment",
       y = "response (count)") +
  geom_smooth(data = data, mapping = aes(x= treatment, y= response, color = early_late), method = "glm", method.args = list(family= poisson),   formula = y ~ x, se = T)
```

Any insights on this will be very appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`.

Comment: glm are linear, try loess or gam for a nonlinear fit